# 3 * 1000000000 overflows as an int, but the variable is long long. Why?

Tags: c++, literals, integer-overflow, long-long

I have a simple c++ app that performs the following calculations

```
long long calcOne = 3 * 100000000;     // 3e8, essentially
long long calcTwo = 3 * 1000000000;    // 3e9, essentially
long long calcThree = 3 * 10000000000; // 3e10, essentially
```

If I write the result of each calculation I get the following output:

```
calcOne = 300000000
calcTwo = -1294967296
calcThree = 30000000000
```

So why does the second calculation fail? As far as I can tell it is within the limits of a long long type (calcThree was larger...).

I am using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10. Thanks in advance.

Comment: integer overflow - you are using an integer literal that fits in an `int` and after the multiplication it overflows - only after that is it converted to `long long` - you can explicitly force the literal to be treated as a `long long` by attaching a `ll` suffix

Comment: I can confirm I get the same result on VS2015, Windows 10 , 64bit build.

Comment: @Rama dead on agree with you, but this has better answers. Going to change the title of this question to make it a bit more useful to searching.

Comment: Another duplicate: [Why does long long n = 2000\*2000\*2000\*2000; overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66354756)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Integer constants are, by default `int`s.

```
1000000000
```

That can fit into an `int`. So, this constant gets parsed as an `int`. But multiplying it by 3 overflows int.

```
10000000000
```

This is too big to an int, so this constant is a `long long`, so the resulting multiplication does not overflow.

Solution: explicitly use `long long` constants:

```
long long calcOne = 3 * 100000000LL;     // 3e8, essentially
long long calcTwo = 3 * 1000000000LL;    // 3e9, essentially
long long calcThree = 3 * 10000000000LL; // 3e10, essentially
```

Answer (score 2):

What you do with a result doesn't affect how that result is calculated. So the fact that you store the result in a `long long` doesn't change the fact that the numbers you multiplied in the second line of code were not `long long`s and so they overflowed. In the third line of code, the constant is a `long long`, so the multiplication is performed on `long long`s.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler saw this

```
long long calcOne = (int) 3 * (int) 100000000;     // 3e8, essentially
long long calcTwo = (int) 3 * (int) 1000000000;    // 3e9, essentially
long long calcThree = (int) 3 * (long long) 10000000000; // 3e10, essentially
```

And so the `calcTwo` right hand value was inferred as an `int` type and then over flowed. You see the over flow as a negative long.

```
long long calcOne = 3LL * 100000000LL;     // 3e8, essentially
long long calcTwo = 3LL * 1000000000LL;    // 3e9, essentially
long long calcThree = 3LL * 10000000000LL; // 3e10, essentially
```

To avoid this in the future, be explicit as to the types of your static values.To tell the compiler a number is a `long long` post fix it with LL.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat : correcting. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Most programming languages rank number types by size. The size/rank/type of a numeric expression is (usually) the type of the highest-ranked value in the expression.

Example: int * double -> double

Your program has:
long long int = int * int.

What's happening is that the result of int * int is an int. So your program will multiply first and treat the result in a signed integer (maximum value ~= 2 billion, so it wraps around into negative numbers). Then, this negative value gets stored in the long long int.

300 million (your first multiplication) fits in an int. No problem there. I'm guessing the third works properly because the compiler is smart enough to know that 30 billion doesn't fit in a 32-bit int and automatically gives it a 64-bit long long int.